# How can a project use wstring without including <string>?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, stl

An existing C++ project builds fine with VS2017 but in VS2019, fails with errors about undefined symbol `std::wstring`.
Digging into the code, `<string>` is never included anywhere but `std::wstring` is used which has me scratching my head how it *ever* built.

I happened to spot in the build logs a reference to `corecrt_wstring`. Google doesn't give me much explanation but I find reference to it here: https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/ucrt/corecrt_wstring.h

Is there some weird version of STL supplied in the Platform SDK or something else going on?

Comment: "`<string>` is never included anywhere"  In the application code.  Most likely it was included by some other system header file on the system where the code was first written.  C++ doesn't restrict system header files from including other header files, but relying on that will definitely make your code non-portable.

Comment: @BenVoigt are you saying Windows headers might include STL files? All I have done is re-target a VS2017 project to VS2019 on the same PC

Comment: That would be quite unusual and poor design (failure to respect layering) but it wouldn't break any rules.  Are you saying that your program doesn't use any standard C++ system header files such as `<iostream>` or `<vector>` or `<algorithm>` and only includes winapi headers?

Comment: Windows headers are C headers, they will never include C++ STL. But it's unlikely that a C++ program doesn't include *any* STL header, either directly or via some 3rd-party header.

Comment: @BenVoigt I found `#include <vector>` but nothing else. The CPP file only includes a couple of things and _they_ don't use STL, neither does `stdafx.h` - those were the things I looked at which is why it's so odd. Most likely it's hidden somewhere I missed I suppose. So is `corecrt_wstring` a red herring?

Comment: @rustyx this CPP project was created in the days of VC++6 when there wasn't really much of an STL ;)

Comment: I bet this is one of those Friday 5pm things once I figure it out!

Comment: Probably the VS2017 version of `<vector>` included `<string>` and the 2019 version doesn't.  Does including `<string>` solve your problems?

Comment: @BenVoigt it does build but makes me uneasy something else could be going on :) I'll test removing `vector` in VS2017 and see if I get an error about `wstring`

Comment: My VS2017 version of `<vector>` includes `<stdexcept>` which includes `<xstring>` and a whole mess of other stuff.

Comment: Instead of trying to make VS2017 produce an error, try enabling `/showIncludes` (C++ -> Advanced area of the project properties)

Comment: @BenVoigt I edited my question as it seems you have solved the mystery, in case you want to add an answer

Comment: If you were able to follow the include chain in your own project, you'd be able to best write your own answer.  You may also want to cite https://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.headers#1 which is the how the Standard expresses the idea I stated in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit really goes to Ben for the hint but it turns out `<vector>` was causing `<string>` to be included on the VS2017 build.